# Slow view rendering using plotly

Tags: python, django-views, plotly

I'm building a dashboard to display on a TV for production data using Django+RaspberryPI but the rendering is quite slow.

The dashboard contains 12 plotly indicator (number type) and 3 bar charts.

At my view, I'm reading a .csv file using pandas, about ~50 lines, then I start creating variables to generates the plotly graphs and pass as context, like below

Create plotly indicator:

```
df_36_ordered = df_detalhado_full.query('Maquina=="3.6"').sort_values(by='Data')    
oee_36 = df_36_ordered['OEE'].iloc[-1:].iloc[0]
```

Create dataframe for bar plot:

```
df_36_historico = df_36_ordered[['dia_semana', 'OEE']].tail(6).iloc[:-1]
```

And then I generates the html for all of it:

```
oee_36 = plot(fig, output_type='div', include_plotlyjs=False, show_link=False, link_text='')
```

I'm looking for tips/alternatives on improving rendering the page.

From entering address to full load it's taking 20 seconds.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

- Dask Instead of Pandas, however, your dataset is only 50 lines, I don't know if it will improve processing time.
- Try to implement multithreading to process your graphs simultaneously.
- If you can only use plotly.graph_objects it's will probably make it faster, but harder for a similar result. Try to delete useless feature, plotly give you lot of built in feature when you plot somethings, those features will make your rendering slower

Comment: I will try the miltithreading tip, sounds very good. About the module, you mean when importing? At the moment i'm just doing: import plotly.graph_objects as go and from plotly.offline import plot, those are the only two libs

Comment: It is always a good idea to only import only package you use, however, I don't think it will heavily improve processing time to make very accurate imports. It can be a good idea to investigate with features of plotly you don't use but that are still in the function you call. As you said it for displaying plots on a TV, maybe you don't need interactive features like : zoom, hovering etc...